# Is there some dev tool like firebug on Opera browser?

Tags: browser, opera, firebug

Need some handy tool in opera browser for developing like firebug

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: The blink based Opera uses the same developer tools as Chrome, the following applies to the Presto-based Opera <=V12**

[Opera DragonFly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/) is a fully featured development tool:

- Edit and modify the DOM tree and any CSS live. Click on elements to find them in the DOM.
- Full breakpoint-and-step javascript debugger, including a [remote debugger protocol](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/remote-debugging-with-opera-dragonfly/) for development on any device.
- Network requests, HTTP headers and more. AJAX friendly.
- Very helpful error messages, better tracing than some other tools.
- You can update to the [cutting edge branch](https://dragonfly.opera.com/app/paths-schema.html) to get the latest features. Simply, go to opera:config#DeveloperTools|DeveloperToolsURL and use https://dragonfly.opera.com/app/cutting-edge.

See more information on the [developer blog](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/), or read [more tutorials on its usage at dev.opera.com](http://dev.opera.com/articles/tags/dragonfly/)...

Answer (score 2):

Try [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html).

Answer (score 0):

Found that Opera has some internal tool but its not handy at all

Comment: Upgrade to Opera 9 or 10 - the internal tool gets a lot better. It's called Dragonfly by the way.

Comment: Dragonfly's still in Alpha but very promising